# Are EventBus sticky events automatically removed on the subscriber method?

Tags: java, android, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus

I'm using [GreenRobot's EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/) version 3.0. And there's a section [on the docs](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/) which says that we can post sticky events, and to receive those events we have to subscribe like this:

```
@Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onEvent(MessageEvent event) {
    // Do something with the message.
    // Is the event removed from the bus on this method?
}
```

So, my question is: Once the subscriber receives the sticky event, are they removed from the bus automatically, or do I have to remove them manually?

**Note:** I know I can remove them manually in any other place of my code using the following line:

```
EventBus.getDefault().removeStickyEvent(stickyEvent);
```

But I want to know if I really need to do that inside the subscriber method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, they are not removed.

However, if you are sticking a message just to remove it when somebody reads it, what you are describing is a queue.

Sticky events are like sticky posts in a bulletin board: they are meant to stay "at top" and be viewed by everybody for a period of time.

Answer (score 3):

They remain on the Bus until they are explicitly removed.